# Merge Image to Another's Bottom

Tags: php, image, merge

I have my website's logo and I want to put it to images bottom when I upload it. First step is fill the white background (height is 70px) then put logo to left bottom. How can i do that ?
For Example ;

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. This is the solution

```
<?php
function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result) {

    list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
    list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_x, $height_y + $height_x);
    $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);
    $image_y = imagecreatefrompng($filename_y);

    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

    imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
    imagecopy($image, $image_y, 0, $height_x, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);
    imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);

    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($image_x);
    imagedestroy($image_y);

}

merge('image.jpg', 'simge.png', 'merged.jpg');
```